# Can't animate an Image in a JLabel

Tags: java, image, swing, animation, jlabel

I would like to animate an Image placed in a `JLabel` like you can see below.
[image: Image link]

I have a problem with animation. The code doesn't produce any errors, but it just works in the `void` indefinitely.

Class Obstacle:

```
package imageTest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Obstacle extends JPanel  {

//Position
int posX,posY;
public int getPosX(){
    return this.posX;
}
public void setPosX(int posX){
    this.posX=posX;
}
public int getPosY(){
    return this.posY;
}
public void setPosY(int posY){
    this.posY=posY;
}

public int fctHasard(int borneInf,int borneSup){
    int random = (int)(Math.random() * (borneSup-borneInf)) + borneInf;
    return random;
}

//Image Obstacle
Image imgObstacle =new Image("C:\\Users\\antoine\\Desktop\\imgProjetObstacle.JPG");

JLabel labImgObstacle =null;

public void fctDessinerObstacle(JFrame fenPrincipale, JPanel panPrincipale) throws IOException{

    int posXDepart=fctHasard(0,fenPrincipale.getWidth()),posYDepart=ImageUtil.getImageHeight(imgObstacle.adresseImg);


    posX=posXDepart;
    posY=posYDepart;
    labImgObstacle=imgObstacle.fctAfficherImg(panPrincipale, posX,posY,ImageUtil.getImageWidth(imgObstacle.adresseImg), ImageUtil.getImageHeight(imgObstacle.adresseImg));
    panPrincipale.add(labImgObstacle);

    //fctMouvement(fenPrincipale, labImgObstacle ,panPrincipale,posX,posY);

}

public void fctMouvement(JFrame fenPrincipale, JLabel labImgObstacle , JPanel panPrincipale,int posX ,int posY) throws IOException{
    boolean continuer=true;

    while(continuer){
        posY++;
        labImgObstacle=imgObstacle.fctAfficherImg(panPrincipale, posX,posY,ImageUtil.getImageWidth(imgObstacle.adresseImg), ImageUtil.getImageHeight(imgObstacle.adresseImg));
        panPrincipale.add(labImgObstacle);
        panPrincipale.repaint();//remetlefondvierge
        if(posY==fenPrincipale.getHeight()){
            posX=fctHasard(0,fenPrincipale.getWidth());
            posY=-ImageUtil.getImageHeight(imgObstacle.adresseImg);
            //remet le fond vierge
            labImgObstacle=imgObstacle.fctAfficherImg(panPrincipale, posX,posY,ImageUtil.getImageWidth(imgObstacle.adresseImg), ImageUtil.getImageHeight(imgObstacle.adresseImg));
            panPrincipale.add(labImgObstacle);
        }
    }
}


}
```

EDIT1:

Comment: Why do i need 10reputation to post an image?It's stupid.
Please i really need help

Comment: It is not stupid. The whole system with reputation makes sense and has proved it works on various sites. You managed to insert a link to the image so it's not a that big deal. I now edited your post to show the image correctly.

Comment: @Suseika//why did you edit my message?There were some usefull precision.

Comment: @Alex //Thank you but can you help me on my problem please

Comment: In my opinion Suseika did everything right. He just deleted the unnecessary information - it is fully understandable the way it is now. Unfortunately, **I** am not an expert in Java not to mention animations but **others** on this site definitely are. So just be patient and wait - I'm sure someone will help you soon.

Comment: @Alex//thank it's my first time on stackoverflow and how the web site works it's tottaly new for me.

Comment: Your code does not compile. What is the qualified name for `Image`? The usual `java.awt.Image` does not have a `adresseImg` method.

Comment: See my naswer below i post img too on what i ve actually

Comment: I don't see anything new.

Comment: ah yes they(who?)deleted my comment grrrrrr,like the text editor wasn't eough bad to re writtre all the time ...

Comment: What i ve :
All work but my image doesn't appear on the frame
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/670940Capture.jpg

Comment: Still you did not answer my question and your code still does not compile. Copy paste what you posted here to an empty file in your IDE like we do and tell me if it runs for you.

Answer (score 0):

I try to understand you problem, is it to move a image into a JLabel ? 
In this case, I try just to put an image as icon into a Jlabel and move while clicking on the JPanel as you can see below :

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Main extends JPanel {

    public JLabel label1 ;
    private int x = 100; 
    private int y = 5;

    public Main() {

        setLayout(null);
        setPreferredSize(  new Dimension(640, 480 ) );

        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {               
                x = x + 10;
                y = y + 10;
                label1.setBounds(x + getInsets().left, y + getInsets().top,   label1.getPreferredSize().width,  label1.getPreferredSize().height);
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });


        ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("middle.gif", "a pretty but meaningless splat");

        label1 = new JLabel("Image and Text",icon, JLabel.CENTER);
        add(label1);

        label1.setBounds(x + getInsets().left, y + getInsets().top,   label1.getPreferredSize().width,  label1.getPreferredSize().height);
    }


    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path,
                                               String description) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = Main.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new Main());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

        createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

May be that could be the beginning to animate something ?